# PHP check if string is "." or ".."

Tags: php, scandir

I'm trying to eliminate directories from a statement and I can't seem to get rid of the `.` or `..` directories while using PHP.

```
$album_num = $_POST['album_num'];
$album_directory = "../../galleries";
$albums = array_reverse(scandir($album_directory));
$album = $albums[$album_num];
if($album) {
    if($album !== "." || $album !== "..") { //This line here
        $image = glob($album_directory . "/" . $album . "/*.jpg");
        $image = explode("/", $image[0]);
        $image = end($image);
        echo $album . ":" . $image;
    }
} else {
    echo "halt";    
}
```

The line that has `if($album !== "." || $album !== "..")` does not seem to be working.  Do I need to escape the dots?

Am I able to just delete them from the array to begin with?

Comment: Because it should be `&&` not `||`. You want to check that it's not a dot AND is not a double dot.

Comment: Look at the usenotes in the manual for scandir

Comment: @zerkms, I must be tired.. Thank you - I've changed that and I've gotten another problem now where I am returning 2 blank calls (using an ajax call to get the names).  I've decided in this short time to just delete the two values in the array.  This way it does not make a call

Comment: @Dagon, You've given me an even better solution.  I don't know why I didn't look down that far.  Thank you

Comment: @ntgCleaner I would actually recommend to NEVER check the comments there: they are not moderated and it's a lot of harmful rubbish there. /cc Dagon

Comment: @zerkms,  Thank you for the info.  I usually take those comments with as many grains of salt as I do when I read w3schools. It's more of a stepping stone to understand what's going on

Comment: @ntgCleaner w3schools is so misleading, I installed the [w3schools hider](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/w3schools-hider/igiahejkpbnbnekdaefddmdceocmjpll?hl=en-US)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($album) {
    if($album !== "." && $album !== "..") { //This line here
        $image = glob($album_directory . "/" . $album . "/*.jpg");
        $image = explode("/", $image[0]);
        $image = end($image);
        echo $album . ":" . $image;
    }
}
```

Change your `if` condition from `||` to `&&`

Comment: Code without explanation is not helpful to the community.

Comment: Edited my answer! Thanks for guidance :)

Comment: It explains nothing. Seriously - the answer should tell WHY it was wrong and WHY what you provided now fixed it.

Answer (score -2):

Use != instead of !==

I suppose u don't want that album evaluate to !==

```
$album_num = $_POST['album_num'];
$album_directory = "../../galleries";
$albums = array_reverse(scandir($album_directory));
$album = $albums[$album_num];
if($album) {
    if($album != "." || $album != "..") { //This line here
        $image = glob($album_directory . "/" . $album . "/*.jpg");
        $image = explode("/", $image[0]);
        $image = end($image);
        echo $album . ":" . $image;
    }
} else {
    echo "halt";    
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `!==` operator does ? How could `$album` variable be evaluated to `!==` in that context ?

Comment: Yes, that would not. Apologies.